# JavaScript tries to load CSS file but path is incorrect

Tags: wordpress

At the moment I'm trying to create my own WordPress blog with an own theme. It works really good so far but I have one problem: I use the skel.js and this tryes to load a css file. which can't be found because it looks under:

> /wp-admin/css/style.css

I'm really new to WordPress soI have no idea how I can tell the JS file that it has to look in the specific theme folder and there in the subfolder css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should go in your functions file. Then your css should go into your css folder in your theme

```
function enqueue_additional_stylesheets() {
    // Register the style like this for a theme:
    wp_register_style( 'css_file', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/yourfile.css', array(), '20150505', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'css_file' );         
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_additional_stylesheets' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either modify the JS file (which may pose a problem when you do version updates), or you can put the CSS file where it's expected. The latter seems like a simple approach.

You could also use an `@import` statement in style.css (at the expected location) to include the other file (at its current location).

```
@import '../themes/theme/subfolder/file.css';
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import

Comment: As you said I do not want to really want to edit the js file. How can I put the file there? Only mannullay over a FTP? I thought that I can not put files there if I install the template over the Wordpress interface...

Comment: I don't recall whether WP offers the ability to add new files. You'll probably need to use FTP. It shouldn't matter how you installed the template.